# convLSTM size mismatch

Tags: conv-neural-network, pytorch, convolution

I'm trying to implement just one cell of Convolutional LSTM and passing a tensor (1,3,128,128) in it. I get a size mismatch error.

```py
    class ConvLSTMCell(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, input_size, input_dim, hidden_dim, kernel_size, bias):
            """
            Parameters
            ----------
            input_size: (int, int)
                Height and width of input tensor as (height, width).
            input_dim: int
                Number of channels of input tensor.
            hidden_dim: int
                Number of channels of hidden state.
            kernel_size: (int, int)
                Size of the convolutional kernel.
            bias: bool
                Whether or not to add the bias.
            """
            super(ConvLSTMCell, self).__init__()

            self.height, self.width = input_size
            self.input_dim  = input_dim
            self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim

            self.kernel_size = kernel_size
            # self.padding     = kernel_size[0] // 2, kernel_size[1] // 2
            self.bias        = bias

            self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=self.input_dim + self.hidden_dim,
                              out_channels=4 * self.hidden_dim,
                              kernel_size=self.kernel_size,
                              #padding=self.padding,
                              bias=self.bias)

        def forward(self, input, prev_state):
            h_prev, c_prev = prev_state
            print('x: {}\nh_prev: {}\nc_prev: {}'.format(x.size(), h_prev.size(), c_prev.size()))
            combined = torch.cat((input, h_prev), dim=1) # concatenate along channel axis
            print('combined: {}'.format(combined.size()))

            combined_conv = self.conv(combined)
            print('combined_conv: {}'.format(combined_conv.size()))
            cc_i, cc_f, cc_o, cc_g = torch.split(combined_conv, self.hidden_dim, dim=1)
            print('cc_i: {}\ncc_f: {}\ncc_o: {}\ncc_g: {}'.format(cc_i.size(), cc_f.size(),   cc_o.size(), cc_g.size()))

            i = torch.sigmoid(cc_i)
            f = torch.sigmoid(cc_f)
            o = torch.sigmoid(cc_o)
            g = torch.tanh(cc_g)
            print('i: {}\nf: {}\no: {}\ng: {}'.format(i.size(), f.size(), o.size(), g.size()))

            c_cur = f * c_prev + i * g
            h_cur = o * F.tanh(c_cur)
            print('c_cur: {}\nh_cur: {}'.format(c_cur.size(), h_cur.size()))

            return h_cur, c_cur

        def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
            return (Variable(torch.zeros(batch_size, self.hidden_dim, self.height, self.width)),
                    Variable(torch.zeros(batch_size, self.hidden_dim, self.height, self.width)))



    x = torch.randn(1,3,128,128)
    model = ConvLSTMCell(input_size=(128,128), input_dim=3, hidden_dim=3, kernel_size=(5,5),
                         bias=True)
    hc = model.init_hidden(batch_size=1)
    if gpu:
        x.cuda()
        model.cuda()
        hc.cuda()

    out = model(x, hc)
    print(out.size())
```

I get the following error:

> x: torch.Size([1, 3, 128, 128])
>
> h_prev: torch.Size([1, 3, 128, 128])
>
> c_prev: torch.Size([1, 3, 128, 128])
>
> combined: torch.Size([1, 6, 128, 128])
>
> combined_conv: torch.Size([1, 12, 124, 124])
>
> cc_i: torch.Size([1, 3, 124, 124])
>
> cc_f: torch.Size([1, 3, 124, 124])
>
> cc_o: torch.Size([1, 3, 124, 124])
>
> cc_g: torch.Size([1, 3, 124, 124])
>
> i: torch.Size([1, 3, 124, 124])
>
> f: torch.Size([1, 3, 124, 124])
>
> o: torch.Size([1, 3, 124, 124])
>
> g: torch.Size([1, 3, 124, 124])
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "trial.py", line 87, in
>
> out = model(x, hc)
>
> File "/Users/abcde/opt/anaconda3/envs/matrix/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 541, in **call**
>
> result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
>
> File "trial.py", line 66, in forward
>
> c_cur = f * c_prev + i * g
>
> RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (124) must match the size of tensor b (128) at non-singleton >dimension 3

I'm wish to build a network of 17 cells using this and I want to use the output of every cell to calculate loss against the ground truth. Ground truth are 18 (3,128,128) images.

How do I get my network to output hidden states of the same size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outputs are smaller because of border effects - the convolution operation only computes values at coordinates where the kernel can fully fit within input shape. The simplest solution would be to apply padding to your convolution layer (which you seem to have already tried, was there anything wrong with that?). If your kernel is of size 5, you should pad by 2 and then the convolution output will be of the same shape as input.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't remember commenting that part out :| , Thanks for noticing. That worked! I was working on a lot of projects simultaneously so must have missed that.